# Jade Image: Is there a way to get image dimensions?

Tags: image, pug, dimensions, getimagesize

Is there a way to get the dimensions (`width` & `height`) of an image using jade - similar to how PHP uses `getimagesize`?

Answer (score 0):

No. Jade is only responsible for templating; it is not a full-on ecosystem like PHP. You need a separate [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size) to do that.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I assumed, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something